# Preserve key:value values in text while regex replacing non-word characters in keys (Notepad++)

Tags: python, regex, notepad++, key-value, pcre

Trying without luck in Notepad++ to replace any non-word characters \W with underscore _ from a block of multi-line text, with exception to (and right of) a colon : (which doesn't occur on every line- something of space-delineated hierarchy, terminating in a key-value pair). A python solution could be of use as well, as I'm trying to do other things with it once reformatted. Example:

```
This 100% isn't what I want   
  Yet, it's-what-I've got currently: D@rnit :(  
This_100_is_what_I_d_like: See?  
  Indentation_isn_t_necessary  
    _to_maintain_but_would_be_nice: :)<-preserved!
  I_m_Mr_Conformist_over_here: |Whereas, I'm like whatever's clever.| 
If_you_can_help: Thanks 100.1%!
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to contain an example of an input and what you want the output to look like?

Comment: My example already has a before and after. The first 2 lines illustrate what I have- non-word characters that do not follow a colon. The rest of the lines illustrate what I'd like- all non-word characters that do not follow a colon replaced with an underscore.

Comment: That isn't immediately obvious from your example. In the future I'd suggest showing the same text, before and after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit that I'm answering an off-topic question I just liked the problem. Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>,  enable Regular Expressions in N++ then search for:

```
(:[^\r\n]*|^\s+)|\W(?<![\r\n])
```

And replace with:

```
(?1\1:_)
```

Regex has two main parts. First side of outer alternation which matches leading spaces of a line (indentation) or every thing after first occurrence of a colon, and second side which matches a non-word character except a carriage return `\r` or newline `\n` character (in negative lookbehind) to preserve linebreaks. Replacement string is a conditional block which says if first capturing group is matched replace it with itself and if not replace it with a `_`.

Comment: Thank you! That met my need and gave me a clearer understanding of the negative lookbehind and conditional block, which I can apply to other match cases.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing a better description of what you're trying to do, I don't think you'll be able to do it from inside notepad++ using a single regular expression. However, you could write a python script that scrolls through your document, one line at time, and sanitizes anything to the left of a colon (if one exists)

Here's a quick and dirty example (untested). This assumes `doc` is an open file pointer to the file you want to sanitize

```
import re

sanitized_lines = []
for line in doc:
    line_match = re.match(r"^(\s*)([^:\n]*)(.*)", line)
    indentation = line_match.group(1)
    left_of_colon = line_match.group(2)
    remainder = line_match.group(3)

    left_of_colon = re.sub(r"\W", "_", left_of_colon)

    sanitized_lines.append("".join((indentation, left_of_colon, remainder)))

sanitized_doc = "".join(sanitized_lines)
print(sanitized_doc)
```

Comment: I don't want to replace any colon or anything to the right of one at all. Anything else must be [A-z0-9_]. So yes, I would like to replace whitespace with underscores, provided they do not fall to the right of a colon.

Comment: Thank you, and yes, I should have been clearer. As with Thm Lee's solution, I will look to incorporate this in a more fulsome python script which may better suit my needs in the longer run.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this python script,

```
ss="""This 100% isn't what I want   
  Yet, it's-what-I've got currently: D@rnit :(  
If you can help: Thanks 100.1%!"""

import re
splitcapture=re.compile(r'(?m)^([^:\n]+)(:[^\n]*|)$')
subregx=re.compile(r'\W+')
print(splitcapture.sub(lambda m: subregx.sub('_', m.group(1))+m.group(2), ss))
```

in which first I tried to match each line and capture 2 parts separately(the `one part` not containing '`:`'character is capured to `group 1`, and the other possible part started with '`:`' and goes on to the end of the line is captured to `group 2`), and then implemented replacing process only on group 1 captured string and finally joined 2 parts, `replaced group 1` + `group 2`

And output is

```
This_100_isn_t_what_I_want_
_Yet_it_s_what_I_ve_got_currently: D@rnit :(  
If_you_can_help: Thanks 100.1%!
```

Comment: Thank you for the python solution. While revo's answer is the best fit for this particular case, I will look to incorporate yours into a more fulsome script.